# Excel VBA cut and paste rage repeatedly

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, paste

I am a complete novice in using VBA and trying to cut and copy a range repeatedly.
I was searching and trying my code around, but gets nowhere...

For example, say the whole data in a range (A1:M1084) consist of blocks of 124 rows and 13 columns.
So the first block is in (A1:M124).
The second data block is currently in (A125:M248), and would like to cut it and paste it next to the first block, leaving a column space (N) in between, to (O1:AA248).
Then, repeat the process until the end of the row (this time 1084, but can be any other number), keep pasting the next block (A249: M372) next to the second block, to (AC1:AO248), and so forth...

If anyone could please help, much appreciated!

Comment: can you please share demo screensheet with your desire output please? so i can help in  this  regarards.

Comment: I just saw your message and sorry for my late reply. I could resolve it myself and also I got another answer which runs more efficiently than my code. So it is fine now. Many thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
Sub MoveBlocks()

    Dim rowCount As Integer, colCount As Integer
    Dim inRow As Integer
    Dim blockSize As Integer
    Dim colOffset As Integer

    blockSize = 124
    rowCount = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    colCount = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

    For inRow = blockSize + 1 To rowCount Step blockSize
        colOffset = Int(inRow / blockSize) * (colCount + 1)
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(blockSize, colCount)).Offset(0, colOffset).Value2 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(blockSize, colCount)).Offset(inRow - 1, 0).Value2
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(blockSize, colCount)).Offset(inRow - 1, 0).ClearContents
    Next inRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not see your answer before I figured it out myself. I can learn a lot from you answer that I do not need to count columns manually as I did!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that I had to accept an answer. Your answer was terrific - works very efficiently! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

After all, I got an answer myself with so many trials and errors. Posting if it maybe of any use. Also, if there is any other more efficient code, would be happy to have!

---

```
Sub Cutrange()

  Dim i As Long
  Dim Lrow As Long
  Lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  Dim oRange As Range, dRange As Range
  Set oRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(124, 14))
  Set dRange = Cells(1, 1)

  For i = 1 To Lrow 
    oRange.Offset(124 * i).Cut Destination:=dRange.Offset(, 14 * i)
  Next i
End Sub
```