# Cut and paste dynamic ranges of data repeatedly

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort 1,8 million data points for data analysis.

I need to automate the following:

Cut a range of data in x sequential rows with identical Sequence numbers in column B.
[image: this is how the data looks right now]

Then paste it onto the right next to the previous range.
[image: this is how I would like the data to]

I found [Excel VBA cut and paste rage repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541826/excel-vba-cut-and-paste-rage-repeatedly)

```vb
Sub Cutrange()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim oRange As Range, dRange As Range
    Set oRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(124, 14))
    Set dRange = Cells(1, 1)

    For i = 1 To Lrow 
        oRange.Offset(124 * i).Cut Destination:=dRange.Offset(, 14 * i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code cuts and pastes a pre-determined range of cells (124x14). In my data, the number of rows (to be cut and pasted) needs to change based on how many rows have the same Sequence number.

Comment: It seems you're splitting the data on the `Sequence nr` column. What I might do (at least initially): have a `While` loop that checks that column for the current `Sequence nr` value. If it's a match, increment a `number_row` variable (this variable will tell you how many rows to move). Once a new row has been encountered, move the data over (based on the number_row variable) over to the range you need, then go on to a new `While` loop to do the same thing on the next set. It may be easier to house the `While` loop in a `For` loop, or you can just check if the next cell is empty.

Comment: Are the number of columns in the range always the same?

Comment: Are there any gaps in the sequence numbers in column B? Blank rows or missing sequence numbers? It would be wise to check first with a routine that just checks the integrity of column B

Comment: The maximum number of rows in a spreadsheet is 1,048,576 rows which is less than your figure of 1.8M - how do you handle this?

Comment: You need the headers. But do you also need the formatting i.e. would copying just values be enough since it's more efficient, especially on a larger dataset? Also, keep in mind that there are only `16384` columns which would allow only a maximum of `1638` sequence numbers.

Comment: @user10186832 Thank you for your replies! Yes, the number of columns is always 9. There are no blank rows in column B, but there are missing sequence numbers. I am importing the data from .txt files - I will just start a new document if I run out of the column with. I won't run out of the rows, as my longest sequence is 800 rows.

Comment: @VBasic2008 thank you for your comment. There is no formatting I need to copy to the new location, pasting the values is enough.

Comment: @jordanz thank you for your help! I will try to follow your instructions. I am a very beginner programmer, so might take a while :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HStack Groups of Data (VBA)

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HStackGroups()
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "B2"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "B2"
    Const UNIQUE_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const COLUMN_GAP As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL).CurrentRegion
    Dim hData(): hData = srg.Rows(1).Value
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count - 1 ' no headers
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Resize(srCount).Offset(1).Value
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim sr As Long, drCount As Long, srString As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        srString = CStr(sData(sr, UNIQUE_COLUMN))
        If Not dict.Exists(srString) Then
            Set dict(srString) = New Collection
        End If
        dict(srString).Add sr
        If dict(srString).Count > drCount Then drCount = dict(srString).Count
    Next sr
    
    drCount = drCount + 1 ' 1 for headers
    Dim dCount As Long: dCount = cCount + COLUMN_GAP
    Dim dcCount As Long
    dcCount = dict.Count * dCount - COLUMN_GAP
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim Coll, Item, sc As Long, d As Long, dr As Long, dc As Long
    
    For Each Coll In dict.Items
        dc = d * dCount
        For sc = 1 To cCount
            dData(1, dc + sc) = hData(1, sc)
        Next sc
        dr = 1
        For Each Item In Coll
            dr = dr + 1
            For sc = 1 To cCount
                dData(dr, dc + sc) = sData(Item, sc)
            Next sc
        Next Item
        d = d + 1
    Next Coll
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    
    With dfCell
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, dws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Clear
    End With
    
    drg.Value = dData
    
    drg.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    MsgBox "Groups hstacked.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU so very much! Your code works perfectly as needed. You are an absolute life saver!